# Speed up Retrieving File Size from remote Url

Tags: c#

Could someone help me speed up retrieving filesize from remote url?
I have 400+ links to check without downloading.

I'm able to check the file size but it takes about 5 minutes to finish
the total file size is 1.45 GB.

maybe you could suggest how to speed up.

here's my current code

```
public static async Task<string> GetFileSize(Uri uriPath)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriPath);
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
    webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36";

    using (var webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        return webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length");
    }
}

public static string FormatFileSize(long bytes)
{
    var unit = 1024;
    if (bytes < unit)
    {
        return $"{bytes} B";
    }
    var exp = (int)(Math.Log(bytes) / Math.Log(unit));
    return $"{bytes / Math.Pow(unit, exp):F2} " +
           $"{("KMGTPE")[exp - 1]}B";
}
```

usage:

```
string result = string.Empty;
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
long num = 0;
foreach (string urls in tbResult.Lines)
{
    Uri url = new Uri(urls);
    long info = (Convert.ToInt32(await Task.Run(() => Utils.GetFileSize(url))));
    num += info;
}
Console.WriteLine(Utils.FormatFileSize(num));
Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed is limited by the network / server response time for each request.
The key to the problem is to parallize the requests. Until now only after a request has finished the next one is issued. Especially if the URIs are pointing to different servers, running requests in parallel is suitable (in order to behave friendly and not putting too much pressure on a single server).

Naive/Brute force way of parallizing is running all requests at once like:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
foreach (string urls in tbResult.Lines)
{
     Uri url = new Uri(urls);
     tasks.Add(Utils.GetFileSize(url));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
foreach (var task in tasks) {
    long info = Convert.ToInt32(task.Result);
    num += info;
}
```

Comment: Wow! it's really fast! it's only takes 3secs

Total Links: 475
Total File Size: 1.45 GB
Elapsed Time: 0h 0m 3s 64.3ms

Comment: I'm gonna try this to other process like getting strings from url or reading json file
I'll post when I succeed :)

Comment: Bonning. could you give me example how I can properly cancel it? 
It takes 1minute to cancel the process using cancellation token

Answer (score 0):

Alright finally I found best solution
Thanks to @Ralf Bonning and @Tom W for suggesting the Interlocked method

Here's the final code:

```
        long sum = 0;
        long localSum = 0;
        var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (string urls in URL)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(urls);
            tasks.Add(GetTotalBytes(url));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            localSum += Convert.ToInt32(task.Result);
        }
        return (Utils.FormatFileSize(Interlocked.Add(ref sum, localSum)));
```

RESULT:

```
Total URL: 355
Filsize: 1.14 GB
Elapsed Time: 0h 0m 2s 50.8ms
```

Comment: Minor code quality note: the expression `num += info;` is not atomic and so is not thread-safe and so you are introducing a (probably minor) bug here. Two threads entering this expression can each read the original value of `num` before adding to it, and the second completion of the expression therefore loses the argument `info` leading to an underestimation. To improve this you can use [Interlocked.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add).

Comment: Ow thank you for this advice. I'm always using it but I will change it from now on:)

By the way, my problem is I can't cancel the process. the cancellation token isn't working

Comment: Hi again @TomW I've already updated the code. Am I doing right with using Interlocked?

Comment: only if you meant to add 1 to the number rather than the number of bytes. If you want to add the number of bytes, equivalent to the previous code sample, use `Add`.

Comment: Actually I only want the total so that I can compute the total file size

Comment: like this?  num += Interlocked.Add(ref info, 1);

Comment: I think this is what you mean? I'll update the code